# Redirecting a login by role in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I have created 2 roles for my ASP.NET site, Admin and Members. On Login, I want to redirect them to pages as per their roles. If user is Admin, it gets redirected to admin area and if member, redirect to member's area. I've been able to get it working for admin, but for members, it just refreshes the page and even the login status doesn't change.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assignment7run.WebForm5" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 508px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"  runat="server">
    <h1 style="font-family: Georgia" class="auto-style2">Login to jQuery Society</h1>
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" CreateUserText="Sign Up for an account on jQuery Society" CreateUserUrl="~/SignUp.aspx" MembershipProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
</asp:Login>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
<br />

</asp:Content>
```

The code behind. Even the admin login started to work when I added the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, true); line to function. When I add it to Members, the page doesn't run.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Assignment7run
{
    public partial class WebForm5 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                    Response.Redirect("~/NoAccess.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
            {
                e.Authenticated = true;
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Admin"))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, true);
                    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/adminWelcome.aspx");
                }

                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Members"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Members/MemberPage.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move setAuthCookie and then show your code on page MemberPage.aspx cuz error on this page.
Without setAuthCookie you always will be return on page Auth, but when you set it, you will redirect on new page what you need and got it error

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
            {
                e.Authenticated = true;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, true); //Do It
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Admin"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/adminWelcome.aspx");
                }

                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Members"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Members/MemberPage.aspx");
                }
            }
```